# Как переписать DFSR в DFS?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-studio, visual-c++, графы

Есть класс который считывает ребра (в формате (2, 4)) и решает задачу сильно связных компонент. Все отлично работает. Но когда ребер не 19, а например 10000 происходит переполнение стека из-за функции **DFSR**

```
void Graph::DFSR(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> G, int vertex)
{
m_ReadyTest.push_back(vertex); // V как протестированная
// для каждого ребра (s, v) в G
for (auto i : G)
{
    if (vertex == i.first)
    {
        bool go(false);
        // если V еще не протестирован 
        for_each(m_ReadyTest.begin(), m_ReadyTest.end(), 
            [=, &go] (int x)
                {
                    if (x == i.second)
                        go = true;
                });
        if (!go)
        {
            // DFSR(G, V)
            DFSR(G, i.second);
        }
    }
}
++m_time;
auto tmpProcT = make_pair(vertex, m_time); // t = t + 1
m_ProcessingTime.push_back(tmpProcT);      // f[V] = t время завершения обработки вершины V
}
```

Собственно как я не пытался переписать функцию без рекурсии (использовал цикл + stack)... то вылетает, то не правильно считает. Вообщем нужна ваша помощь.

p.s. ЛИБО как вариант. Объясните подробно как увеличить стек в VisualStudio 15
p.s.s. заранее спасибо!

Вот мой вариант:

```
void Graph::DFS(vector<pair<int, int>> G, int vertex)
{
/*1*/
m_ReadyTest.push_back(vertex); // V как протестированная

/*2*/
stack<int> iStack;
iStack.push(vertex); // V ложим на вершину стека

/*3*/
while (!iStack.empty()) // пока стек НЕ пустой
{

/*4*/
    int iU = iStack.top();
    for (auto i : G) // ищим все V для U
    {
        if (iU == i.first) // i.second -- V
        {

/*5*/
            bool go(false);
            // если V еще не протестирован 
            for_each(m_ReadyTest.begin(), m_ReadyTest.end(),
                [=, &go](int x)
            {
                if (x == i.second) // V протестирован
                    go = true;
            });
            if (!go)
            {
 /*6*/
                m_ReadyTest.push_back(i.second); // V как протестировану

 /*7*/
                iStack.push(i.second); // V в голову стеку
            }
        }
    }// вершина обработана...

    if (!iStack.empty() && iU == iStack.top())
    {
        iStack.pop();// удаляем U из стека
        ++m_time;
        auto tmpProcT = make_pair(iU, m_time); // t = t + 1
        m_ProcessingTime.push_back(tmpProcT);  // f[V] = t время завершения обработки вершины V
    }
}
}
```

Результаты мелких тестов совпадают, результат теста на 55к ребер:
[image: Результат последнего теста]

Боюсь что при решении задачи, а там 5105043 ребра (насколько помню), результат совсем плох будет. 
**п.с. Хоть убей, не понимаю, что еще не правильно у меня в функции DFS.**

Comment: я думаю у вас один выход - это это всё-таки добить версию без рекурсии ... а увеличивать стек в visual studio это уже ненужные извращения.

Comment: Угу, присоединяюсь. Покажите ещё вашу попытку с циклом и стеком.

Comment: Добавил свой DFS.

Comment: Из тестовых входных данных правильно работает с 2/3. В 1/3 происходит просто зацикливание.

Comment: `int iU = iStack.top();`: вам в любом случае надо удалять вершину из стека, раз вы её проходите. И для протестированных вершин заведите лучше `unordered_set`. И локальный, а то вдруг там от прошлого пробега что-то останется.

Comment: С хештаблами все ясно. Что мне с функцией делать. Если удалять вершину со стека сразу вообще ересь получается(((

Comment: Я понял почему происходит зацикливания. В одном тестовом примере есть графы которые направлены с какой то вершины в вершину 10! И когда начинается обработка вершины 10 и происходит зацикливание ибо с этой вершины нету графов. В DFSR в таком случае просто заканчивается функция. А вот как мне исправить DFS?

Comment: ОБНОВИЛ код DFS. Три мелких теста посчитал успешно. А вот в тесте на 55к ребер результат не совсем совпал: **7578 2165 1 1 1 1 1...**
а корректный результат такой: **7578 1996 1 1 1 1 1...**

Comment: Я так понял больше мне никто ничем не поможет((

Answer (score 4):

Увеличить стек можно так: *Свойства проекта → С/С++ → Командная строка* и в поле *Дополнительные параметры* вписываете `/F %количество_байт%`, то есть:

```
/F 20971520 – это стек в 20 Мб
```

[Вот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tdkhxaks.aspx) статья об этом на MSDN, там же есть и другие способы увеличения стека.

P.S. лучше конечно переписать функцию, но для этого покажите, как вы пытались это сделать и где оно вылетало и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

```
void Graph::DFSR(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &G, int vertex)
```

Comment: Та это вообще не имеет никакого значения в данном случае.

Comment: Можно подсчитать что у вас хранится на стек фрейме на каждый вызов - `for (auto i : G)` : 8 байт как минимум можно переписать на `for (const auto &i : G)` плюс вершина и ссылка на граф и того 20 байт плюс минус - на 1000 вершин точно хватит.  Оригинальный код без ссылки как минимум медленее плюс добавляет члены вектора в каждый фрейм - а зачем ?

Comment: В пятом тестовом файле данных почти 55к графов. Ну мне не сложно проверить. Просто суть задания как раз в том, что бы не позволить выполнить его стандартным путем. По этому я сразу и не заморачивался.

Comment: по прежнему вылетает ошибка переполнения

Comment: К стати в файле с данными по которым нужно дать результат (не тестовые) -- 5105043 графа. Только сейчас увидел.